# Triangular and pentagonal numbers in $q$-series

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider the following two infinite series
$$\sum_{n\geq0}a(n)q^n=\prod_{k\geq1}\frac1{(1-q^k)^2(1-q^{5k})^2} \,\,\,\, \text{and} \,\,\,
\sum_{n\geq0}b(n)q^n=\prod_{k\geq1}\frac1{(1-q^k)^2(1-q^{7k})^2}.$$
Denote the triangular numbers and pentagonal numbers by $t_n:=\binom{n+1}2$ and $\omega_n:=\frac{n(3n+1)}2$, respectively.

> **QUESTION.** Are these two congruences true modulo $4$?
> $$\sum_{n\geq0}a(4n+3)q^n\equiv \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}q^{5t_n} \qquad \text{and} \qquad 
> \sum_{n\geq0}b(4n+3)q^n\equiv 2\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}q^{14\omega_n}.$$

Comment: It seems that $\omega_n$ does not appear in your question - would one of $t_n$ be $\omega_n$ instead?

Comment: Ouch. You are right.

Comment: Isn't that just a matter of [q-series multisection](https://grail.eecs.csuohio.edu/~somos/multiq.html)?

Comment: True, this is 4-sectioning but the point is always to determine each section explicitly. Is it not? After all Ramanujan's famous $\sum p(5n+4)q^n=5\frac{(q^5)_{\infty}^5}{(q)_{\infty}^6}$ is also multi-sectioning.